# Middleman Frontmatter flag for build

Tags: build, yaml, middleman

Is it possible in middleman to add a frontmatter flag like "use_in_build" with values true or false. And skip these during build process?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you do that using the frontmatter, but you can specify files to ignore in `config.rb`.

```
configure :build do
  ignore /page.html/ # Regular expression
end
```

Is that any use to you?

Answer (score 0):

There is published: false for the middleman-blog extension. Maybe you can extend this to the rest of the middleman build somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your need for setting this flag, it might suffice to use the filename convention: any file that begins with an underscore (`_`) is skipped during build.